# Import .flac to After Effects CS6

Tags: after-effects, editing, audio, windows, adobe

How can i import a simple .flac audio file to After Effects?

I didn't find one single plugin/presets or answer at Adobe's site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly Adobe doesn't support FLAC in any of their video products. The only Adobe product that supports it so far is Audition.

Though there is this [great and open source plugin](http://valion.net/flacimporter64/) that works just fine with CS6 even though it was made for CS5. Plugins made for CS5 are usually compatible with CS6 and CC.

For CS4 there is a 32bit version of the same plugin: http://valion.net/flacimporter/

Answer (score 1):

FLAC files can be opened into Adobe Audition and saved out into a different file format that is compatable.